# is it siteMesh as grails UI framework responsive or not?

Tags: grails, sitemesh

I decided to learn Grails but before it I have 2 concern about siteMesh as web framework.
1.Is it responsive UI framework?
2.Do it support Right-to-Left?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitemesh on its own is just a way to assemble different blocks of HTML together into one final HTML page - whether or not your layout is "reponsive" or supports RTL isn't a concern of sitemesh, but rather it depends on how you write the blocks of HTML that sitemesh will assemble.

I have a number of projects that use the Bootstrap CSS framework within the sitemesh layout to achieve a responsive design.

Comment: agree this is a fact in any other framework whit some web-page layout and decoration framework, you inject responsive using some awesome frameworks like as Ian said bootstrap or zurb foundation to name some